# MVC3 map routes to static file structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Let's say I have an MVC application that routes requests according to the standard /{controller}/{action} pattern.  I also want to be able return static files from a nested directory structure.  For example, I want the root URL:

```
/MyApplication/Static/folder/subfolder/somefile.xml
```

to return the file at the physical location ~/Static/folder/subfolder/somefile.xml, and so on.

Is this what the "MapPageRoute" method is for?  If so, is it possible to do something like this?

```
routes.MapPageRoute("static_file_router", "Static/*", "~/Static/*")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use IIS to map this instead.  Static files don't need to go through the ASP.NET pipeline and slow down the requests unnecessarily.

`MapPageRoute` is for legacy WebForms pages.

e.g.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", 
                    "SalesReport/{locale}/{year}/{*queryvalues}", 
                    "~/sales.aspx");
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute.aspx